# In the US, does a stop sign take priority over a red light?

Tags: usa, traffic

I've recently encountered a [peculiar road arrangement](https://www.google.com/maps/@47.6495983,-122.356974,133m/data=!3m1!1e3) in Seattle. As you can see from the graphic below, Cremona St is merging with Nickerson St. There's a stop sign on Cremona and a traffic light on Nickerson. The line where cars are supposed to stop before the traffic light is to the left of Cremona St.

Satellite view:

[image]

View from Cremona St:

[image]

View from Nickerson St:

[image]

The question then becomes: can a car driving via Cremona St ignore the red light after the stop sign, presuming no pedestrians are present? Does it matter that the stop line for cars on Nickerson St is located prior to the spot where Cremona St is merging in?

I got my license in Europe and haven't seen such traffic arrangements back home.

Comment: Related generic question (now closed): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99447/right-of-way-in-case-of-both-traffic-lights-and-traffic-signs

Comment: It seems to me that this traffic light is solely there to serve as a pedestrian crosswalk. So it is fairly unlikely that the light would be red without a pedestrian present.

Comment: In Sweden this arrangement would have required a [STOPP | SIGNAL](https://transportstyrelsen.se/4ad652/globalassets/global/vag/vagmarken/vagmarken-nedladdning/c34.png) sign that tells you "Yes I know, the signal is over there, but you have to stop _here_ and wait."

Comment: I have seen such a setup in Europe / Germany several times. One is 200m from my flat. I don't know where you have been driving so far, but this kind of setup is not limited to the US.

Comment: Some traffic engineer needs to be fired for this horribly confusing abomination. Of course, the US so massively overuses STOP signs; the vast majority of them, including this one, should be YIELD signs. It should also have a STOP HERE ON RED sign to indicate that the light also controls. And the NO PARKING sign is just ridiculous.

Comment: @Sabine oh that’s interesting! Can you add a Google Maps link?

Comment: The crazy thing is, this confusing arrangement doesn't even seem necessary, because just 100m or less further along the road there's another place to merge _after_ the traffic light.  There's a plethora of places to merge along Nickerson.  Maybe the Seattlites are used to it, though.

Answer (score 8):

You can never drive through a red light under any (non-emergency) circumstances, other than turning right (in certain situations). The process for someone driving Cremona to merge onto Nickerson would be:

1. Come to a complete stop at the stop sign.
2. If it's safe to do so (no oncoming vehicles) merge onto Nickerson
3. If the traffic light is red, stop at the traffic light or behind the car(s) at the traffic lights. It doesn't matter if there are pedestrians or not. You will always stop here if it's red. If there is enough traffic such that merging is not possible, you may have to wait longer to be able to merge onto Nickerson, behind that stop sign.
4. Go when permitted by the traffic light.

This means that you may have to stop and start a few times, but the Stop sign only applies to Cremona St and doesn't give you right-of-way through the traffic light after you've passed it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I haven't been at this particular junction but what I would probably do here is wait behind the stop sign until the sign is green _and_ the road is clear. There just might not be enough space before the light to line up after merging. Which, I think, what caused the confusion by OP.

Comment: "You can never drive through a red light under any (non-emergency) circumstances": that is incorrect.  The red light controls traffic at the stop line, but the US engages in the confusing practice of placing traffic signals on the far side of an intersection.  This means that, for example, traffic turning from a road with a green signal must pass through a red signal as it leaves the intersection to continue on the intersecting road.  It is not at all clear that the intersection presented in this question isn't analogous.

Comment: +1 to @phoog - from the aerial photo there is a white line on Nickerson *before* the merge from Cremona, but no white line after. I would have thought the red light controls stopping at the white line on the road.

Comment: Yes, this answer is wrong.  The stop line on Nickerson is clearly to the left of the merging flow on Cremona and there is a *clear stop line* on Cremona also, so the right thing to do is *remain stopped behind the stop line at Cremona* until the light turns green - then merge only when safe.  The stop light is **strictly** for the pedestrian crossing, which a merging vehicle from Cremona would cross (driving over people) if the light was red to allow people to cross.

Comment: In some states red lights can be treated as stop signs

Comment: @abligh yes, but that stop line appears to have been added as an afterthought.

Comment: The point of a Stop sign is to force the driver to come to a standstill and make a thorough assessment of the traffic situation. There aren't different levels of priority. Perhaps it was situated there because of the proximity to the crossing which might be overlooked when looking in the opposite direction to merge with the main road traffic. If in doubt: wait.

Comment: In Germany, things work exactly as described in the answer. As a result, in times of heavy traffic, you sometimes see people get out of their car to activate the pedestrians' green light, so they can merge easily into the main road.

Comment: "You can never drive through a red light under any (non-emergency) circumstances" In addition to what @phoog said many states allow turning right on red after a full stop. It means that crossing a red light that applies to you is a normal case in US.

Comment: "...the US engages in the confusing practice of placing traffic signals on the far side of an intersection."  Some of us would say that _Europe_ engages in the unpleasant practice of placing traffic signals on the _near_ side of an intersection, so you have to uncomfortably twist your neck to see them.

Comment: ... which is why Europe engages in the pleasant practice of placing repeaters at eye height, so you do not have to twist your neck.
Placing the traffic light at the actual place where you have to stop reduces confusion. It also makes it easier to have separate lights for each lane, operated independently. If the intersection this post is about were in Switzerland for example Cermona st. would just have its own traffic light, and its own green cycle...

Comment: Just like a traffic light has priority over a stop sign, a traffic police officer directing you to stop or to drive would have priority over the traffic light.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka and to further confuse matters, in most states you can turn left on a red light if you are on a one-way street going onto another one-way street, but in some states you can do so even if you are going from a 2-way onto a 1-way.  Also you can sometimes treat them as a stop sign in some states under certain conditions.  For example, if the light is pressure sensitive and it's the middle of the night and you are on a motorcycle, the light may never actually turn.

Comment: Also agreeing with others that this answer is wrong because the stopping point for the light is behind where you would be after a turn. Turning and then stopping would be a good way to get rear ended by someone who is looking left and assuming you made a full turn. Wouldn't be your fault but...

Comment: @KristvanBesien Only parts of Europe do that. The UK (typically) engages in the practice of repeating the traffic lights on the other side of the intersection while Germany engages in the practice of asking drivers to bend their necks awkwardly.

Comment: @Jan, I have not come across an intersection with traffic lights that did not have repeaters at eye level in Germany. Or Switzerland. Or the Netherlands. Or Belgium...

Comment: @KristvanBesien Seriously? I live in Germany, have done so for most of my life. I have been around quite a bit in this country and I could not tell you *one single* traffic light that has an eye-level repeater off the top of my head but probably upwards of 100 that don't. *Sometimes* there are bicycle lights at eye level but they may or may not sync up to the car traffic lights. (Unless of course 'eye level' refers to a person sitting on the upper deck of a double-decker bus but surely that's not what you mean.)

Comment: @jan: Maybe there is just a misunderstanding here. Just searching for pictures "ampel" pictures yielded many examples of what I mean. Traffic lights where there are both lights above the lanes, and repeaters at a lower level on the posts that support the lights. eg, like this: https://audimediacenter-a.akamaihd.net/system/production/media/77654/images/be3851573708a87230aa53360ef24dcf9a912aa0/A195569_full.jpg?1582517342
Ok. Not exactly "eye level", but at a level comfortable for the driver.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Indeed, that level is what I am referring to as the ones that ask drivers to bend their necks awkwardly. [This one at the bottom](https://media.ouest-france.fr/v1/pictures/MjAxNzAzZTdkN2VhMzI4MDkwMDYyZmNhYTk3YWVjMTM2YTczMmU) is what I would have considered a repeater at eye level ;)

Answer (score 5):

Note that there is no stop line before the crosswalk.  Thus the light applies to the stop lines that correspond with the stop signs.

Under normal conditions this is simply a pair of stop signs controlling merging traffic, but if someone wants to use the crosswalk the light will be red and you have to wait for it to turn green before proceeding.

A very unusual situation but it seems perfectly clear to me what to do.  Sometimes the traffic engineers have to do odd things when they have work with existing roads.